# Convert CString to Char*

Tags: c++

I'm using ADO and I retrieve a string data from mysql database.

```
CString         cstrPrivilege;
char*           charPrivilege;
//assume that I have done the database connection
//let said the data is "Admin"
cstrPrivilege = (LPCTSTR)(_bstr_t)m_pRecordset->GetCollect("Privilege");
wcout << cstrPrivilege.GetString() <<endl; // no problem, show "Admin"
```

The problem now is I want to assign convert the `cstrPrivilege` to `charPrivilege` for `strcmp()` purpose.
But I have no idea and I have try a lot of method like:

```
charPrivilege = (LPSTR)(LPCTSTR)cstrPrivilege; 
cout << charPrivilege; // only show the first character, show "A" only
```

and

```
charPrivilege = (LPSTR)(LPCTSTR)cstrPrivilege.GetBuffer(cstrPrivilege.GetLength());
// show "A" only too
```

I had found that my `cstrPrivilege` is in `LPCWSTR` type, but I still have no idea how to convert it. 
Anyone have idea to solve it?